# $\not\exists$ bijective function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to A(\subset\Bbb{R}^m~m>n)$such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function

Suppose $m>n$. Let $A\subset \Bbb{R}^m$ such that $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to A$ is bijective. Show that there exists no such function $f$ such that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are both differentiable.

If $m=n$ then inverse function theorem implies the above statement is wrong. But I can't fathom the relationship between $Df(x)$ and $Df^{-1}(x)$ if they exist, in the case $m\ne n$.

Comment: They won't exist.

Comment: Something is wrong here: can't you take $A = \mathbb{R}^n$ embedded inside $\mathbb{R}^m$ on the first $n$ coordinates, and then $f$ to just be the map $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1, \ldots, x_n, 0, \ldots, 0)$?

Comment: @Joppy the map you describe is not surjective to begin with. Iirc this is a somewhat 'advanced' result in topology, in fact there will not exist homeomorphisms between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $n \neq m$.

Comment: I think I have done it via contradiction. If we assume both $f^{-1}$ and $f$ are differentiable then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$, and by chain rule $Df^{-1}(f(x))\cdot Df(x)=I$. But $Df(x)$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and hence singular, which implies multiplying it with another (singular) matrix can't yield the identity matrix. Hence contradiction.

Comment: @GuidoA. But the map doesn't have to be surjective onto $\mathbb{R}^m$, just onto some subset $A$ inside it. This is why I am a little confused at the question.

Comment: @Joppy my bad, you're absolutely right, your function should meet then the properties of the post.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha I may be missing something here, but doesn't you argument fail since for example $(1,0) \cdot (1,0)^t = 1$ which is the identity matrix on $\mathbb{R}$?